# Primary Key: Slow Inserts?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Defining a column to be a primary in table on SQL Server - will this make inserts slower?

I ask because I understand this is the case for indexes.

The table has millions of records.

Comment: What is the current structure of the table including indexes?

Comment: I would never have a table with millions of rows and NOT have a primary key

Comment: @KM - The OP might already have a unique index on non nullable columns though and is asking whether making it an "official" PK will slow anything down. Perhaps unlikely though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, not necessarily!** Sounds counter-intuitive, but read this quote from [Kim Tripp's blog post](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx):

> **Inserts are faster in a clustered
>   table** (but only in the "right"
>   clustered table) than compared to a
>   heap. The primary problem here is that
>   lookups in the IAM/PFS to determine
>   the insert location in a heap are
>   slower than in a clustered table
>   (where insert location is known,
>   defined by the clustered key). Inserts
>   are faster when inserted into a table
>   where order is defined (CL) and where
>   that order is ever-increasing.

So actually, having a good clustered index (e.g. on a INT IDENTITY column, if ever possible) does speed things up - even insert, updates and deletes!

Comment: Only if the PK gets a clustered index. Great tip, +1.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: which is the system-default on SQL Server, and I bet you - more than 80% of all database tables out in the universe have a clustered PK

Comment: The link returns a 404. Here is where it resides now: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/

Comment: Beware of last page latch contention when insert speeds are your primary concern.  We just dropped our BIGINT Primary key on a table in favor of a composite primary key to avoid the last-page latching issue.  (Too many inserts in the same page due to auto-incrementing primary key)  This took hours of down time due to the Billions of rows in the table...

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys are automatically indexed, clustered if possible and failing that non-clustered.

So in that sense inserts are slightly affected, but of course having no primary key would usually be much much worse, assuming the table needs a primary key.

First measure, identify a problem and then try to optimize. Optimizing away primary keys is a very bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough to create a perceptual performance hit, and the benefits far outweigh the very minor perforamnce issues.   There are very very few scenarios where you should not put a primary key on a table.

Answer (score 0):

The really quick answer is:

Yes.

Primary keys are always indexed (and SQL will attempt a clustered index). Indexes make inserts slower, clustered indexes even more so.

Depending on what your table is used for, you may have a couple of options.

If you do a lot of bulk inserts then reads, you can remove the primary key, insert into a heap (if you have SQL 2008 this can be minimally logged to run even faster) then reassign the key and wait for the index to run.

As an addendum to that, you can also insert using an ORDER BY clause which will keep the inserted rows in correct order for the clustered index.  This will really only help if you are inserting millions of rows at once from a source that is already ordered, though.

Comment: actually: NO - see my post. Having a clustered primary key makes inserts, updates, deletes **faster** than if you have no clustered, primary key (just a "heap")

Comment: @marc_s, your correct to a point, you will actually run into worse throughput if the primary key is a typical auto-incrementing int/bigint. (99% of which are)  This is due to the Last Page Latch Contention issue that arises when too many inserts are occurring concurrently in the last page of the clustered index.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, adding a primary key to a table will slow inserts (which is OK, because *not* adding a primary key to your table will speed up your application's eventual catastrophic failure).

If what you're doing is creating a new table and then inserting millions of records into it, there is nothing wrong with initially creating the table *without* a primary key, inserting all the records, and *then* creating the primary key.  Or use an alternative tool to perform a bulk insert.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, inserts are slowed, especially with several clients doing inserts simultaneously, and more so if your key is sequentially increasing (all inserts occur at the right-most nodes of the index tree, in most database implementations, or at the last page of the table for e.g. clustered SQL Server indices -- both of which scenarios cause resource contention).

That said, SELECTs using the primary key are speeded up quite a bit, and the integrity of your key is guaranteed. Do the right thing first (define primary keys everywhere). Second, measure to see if you cannot meet your performance targets, and whether this is caused by your data integrity constraints. Only then consider workarounds.

Answer (score -2):

No, not necessarily

Regardless, that is not why you would define a primary key on a table.

You define a primary key when it is REQUIRED by the domain model.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. The reasons for defining a PK are irrelevant to the question. For example I came here because I wanted to know if it would be worth it for me to create the PK after inserting lots of rows, rather than on table creation, for performance' sake.

Comment: @eurotrash: Incorrect. The answer has everything to do with the question.

Comment: The question is: "will [defining a PK] make inserts slower?" Your answer: "That's not why you'd define a PK". That hasn't answered the question about whether it will be slower, hence my comment.